# 2007 Honda Civic no 1st or 2nd gear and no reverse

Tags: honda, civic, shifting

This morning on the way home I went to downshift from 3rd to 2nd turning onto my street and it was locked out of 1st and 2nd and had to force it back into 3rd (never grinded only clunked real hard into gear) , shifter won’t even move to left to get into gear . Shifter is stuck in the center and only moves right for 5th and reverse but locked out of reverse too. I was thinking maybe the shift linkage right where it connects to the knob was messed up but I checked it out and nothing seemed out of the ordinary. Any ideas on what could be wrong? Noticed it’s been getting a little difficult to get into 2nd and 3rd lately but never just fully locking up

Comment: I would check all the linkage from the shifter to the transmission for worn, broken or missing bushings.

Comment: I’m looking at the shifter cables on top of the trans right now, nothing is worn, broken, etc the cable that lets the shifter move side to side is jammed it lets me push it back which would to the right inside the car but won’t let me pull it forward which would be to the left

Comment: Even pulled the cable off the linkage going into the trans and it does the same thing it’s jammed somewhere inside the trans

Comment: Look underneath car where the shifter is.

Comment: Is your clutch working normal? Had a civic once and the clutch slave cylinder ha a leak. you could not feel it in the pedal but the pressure was not enough to lift the clutch fully.

Comment: Clutch is fine, it just jammed I put I 3/8 extension under the linkage and slightly pried it forward and it broke loose but still acting difficult to get into 2nd like before